# Can the senate majority leader postpone a vote on impeachment?

Tags: united-states, senate, impeachment, procedure

In an infamous column in the Washington Post entitled [*Mitch McConnell is a Russian asset*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/mitch-mcconnell-is-a-russian-asset/2019/07/26/02cf3510-afbc-11e9-a0c9-6d2d7818f3da_story.html), it's argued that the senate majority leader repeatedly has postponed bills with bipartisan support so they could not be made into law.

Are there any limits on doing that when articles of impeachment have been drafted by the House of Representatives which [need to be voted on by the Senate per the constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_6:_Trial_of_Impeachment)?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this issue is addressed in this question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/45989/lets-say-the-impeachment-procedure-reaches-the-senate-what-next/