# Is there a time constraint on the Senate voting to convict an impeached president?

Tags: united-states, senate, impeachment

This question is mostly what it says in the title. My understanding is that if a president is successfully impeached, the Senate is required to hold a vote on whether or not to convict.

Is there any timeline or guidance on when this has to happen? Or could a controlling member of the Senate that didn't want the vote to be held simply delay the vote for weeks, months, or potentially years until it was no longer relevant?

Comment: See also [Can the senate majority leader postpone a vote on impeachment?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46084/26455).